# Disable a script if google chrome 11 was not found (Html)

Tags: html

Hi how i can make disable a script if google chrome 11 was not found ?
how can I create something like this using a html code ?

this is the script that i want to disable

```html
include ( "../htmlclass.php" );
$codex1 = new \codex1html\cod1();
$codex2->setJSpath('../cod2.php');

$htmlPage = <<< EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% reliable, but you can use the user agent. It's not reliable because other browsers can pretend to be Chrome and v11, and extensions can change the user-agent, etc.
Anyway, to find if it's Chrome 11 you could use something like:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome/11.') !== false)
{
    include ( "../htmlclass.php" );
    $codex1 = new \codex1html\cod1();
    $codex2->setJSpath('../cod2.php');

    $htmlPage = <<< EOF
}
```